# Firebase timestamp value map android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I've looked for answers on this section all day long and I can not seem to grasp my head around it.

I'm currently building my first application. The problem I've encountered is I want the users to see what time the post was created at. I have tried to implement other peoples answers to the question for my app, but I'm not sure how I would go about displaying it on the application it comes up in my Firebase database when it was created.

So the problem is how would I go about setting the timestamp in my view holder?

Below is a snippet of my code.

My post class.

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Post {

public String uid;
public String author;
public String title;
public String body;
public Object creationDate;
public Post() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
}

public Post(String uid, String author, String title, String body, Object creationDate) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.creationDate = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
}

public void convertTime(Long unixtime) {
    Date dateObject = new Date(unixtime);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss");
    dateFormatter.format(dateObject);
}


// [START post_to_map]
@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("uid", uid);
    result.put("author", author);
    result.put("title", title);
    result.put("body", body);
    result.put("dateCreated", creationDate);

    return result;
}
// [END post_to_map]

}
```

---

```
public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView titleView;
    public TextView authorView;
    public TextView bodyView;
    public ImageView mUserImage;
    public TextView timeView;

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titleView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_text);
        authorView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
        bodyView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_body);
        timeView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeStamp);


    }

    public void bindToPost(Post post) {
        titleView.setText(post.title);
        authorView.setText(post.author);
        bodyView.setText(post.body);
    }
```

Thanks for any help in advance! I appreciate it.

Comment: woah you overcomplicated it.

Comment: How so? Could you explain to me thanks.

Comment: You have said you are getting errors, but haven't said what they are! Include more detail about what is going wrong so people can help you

Comment: @LewisMcGeary I'm getting an error regarding Cannot reference method from a non static context if you can see on MyPostClass where I have HashMap<String, Object> date = new Post.getDateCreated(); where I'm trying to call it and put it where in my writeNewPost method

Comment: @Noskes you should update the question so people can understand what the problem is.

Comment: @LewisMcGeary I have updated my question, sorry about the misunderstanding regarding my question.

Comment: @Noskes with the updated post, you are missing one line of code (i'm sure you can find it if you look at the end very carefully).  I did not implement the same way you did, but a different and less coded way. I know your way is similar to Firebase sample, but that is just building blocks.

Comment: @user7568042 thanks for your time answering my question, however whenever I call timeView.setText(post.creationDate); I get an error or am I completely looking in the wrong area?

Comment: What error do you get when you call `timeView.setText(post.creationDate); `?

Comment: @user7568042 Thank you so much! I have resolved my problem now I need to figure out how to convert that timestamp haha

Comment: @Drew I was getting cannot convert object error. So I sorted the error by using timeView.setText(String.valueOf(post.creationDate)); so its now coming up on my application however I need to figure out how to convert them digits into actual time.

Comment: @Noskes  glad to hear you got it fixed.  Look into DateUtils to help you with that

Comment: @user7568042 thanks I sorted out the problem and got everything to work i used the prettyTime library which solved my issues.